# snd_pcm_writei not working after a delay

Tags: c, linux, alsa

I was trying to generate a beep sound using ALSA. 2 beep sounds should be generated, the 2nd one after a delay of 1 second. My code looks like the following.

```
if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (playback_handle)) < 0) {
    printf("cannot prepare audio interface for use \n");
    return -1;
}


for (i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i ++){
    samples[i] = 100*sin(2.0*pi*f*(i/44100.0));
    if ((err = snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, &samples[i], 4)) != 4) {
        printf("write to audio interface failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
}

//snd_pcm_drain(playback_handle);

printf("ending beep !!! \n");
sleep(1);

if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (playback_handle)) < 0) {
    printf("cannot prepare audio interface for use \n");
    return -1;
}
for (i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i ++){
    samples[i] = 100*sin(2.0*pi*f*(i/44100.0));
    if ((err = snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, &samples[i], 4)) != 4) {
        printf("write to audio interface failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Here the first beep is heard properly but the second beep is not OK. Can anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: What happens after the code you've shown?

Comment: After the shown code snippet i am closing playback_handle.

Answer (score 0):

`snd_pcm_write*()` just writes samples to the buffer, but returns immediately when all the samples are in the buffer.

To wait until all samples in the buffer have been played, call `snd_pcm_drain()`.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was solved. The issue was with setting the hw params.